# TypeError: _mappings__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.a[iconName] is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

The example code in `mappings.ts`.

```
import NotificationsIcon from './NotificationsIcon';
import AddIcon from './AddIcon';
import AirplayLineIcon from './AirplayLineIcon';

export const mappings = {
  'notifications': NotificationsIcon,
  'add': AddIcon,
  'airplay-line': AirplayLineIcon
} as const;

export const names = [
  "notifications",
  "add",
  "airplay-line",
} as const 

export type IconName = typeof names[number];
```

This is how the icon component looks.

`notifications: (iconProps: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => JSX.Element;`

I am facing issues when I try to render the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {IconName, mappings} from './mappings';

export const SvgIcon: React.FC<{iconName: IconName, iconSize: number, color:string}> = ({iconName, iconSize, color}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {mappings[iconName]({width: iconSize, height: iconSize, fill: color})}
    </>
  );
};
```

the error `TypeError: _mappings__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.a[iconName] is not a function`

Not sure what i am doing wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to invoke the Icon with JSX like this:

```
const Icon = mappings[iconName]
return <Icon width={iconSize} height={iconSize} fill={color} />
```

or you could use a helper function provided by react:

```
return React.cloneElement(mappings[iconName], {width: iconSize, height: iconSize, fill: color})
```

By the way, I think you can omit the `names` constant inside mappings.ts. You can just do the following instead:

```
export const mappings = {
  'notifications': NotificationsIcon,
  'add': AddIcon,
  'airplay-line': AirplayLineIcon
} as const;

export type IconNames = keyof typeof mappings;
```

I hope I was able to help, cheers!

Comment: For the first soluition
`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Second solution
`index.js:56 Error: React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed undefined.`

Comment: As the error states, your imports don't seem to be correct. If that doesn't fix your problem, please create a codesandbox so that I can assist you further more.

Comment: here is the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-euclid-qglzqc?file=/src/App.tsx, 
it works fine, but the issue is when i do this in storybook

Comment: MrUnknown, thanks  for the comment, i overlooked the exports in my stories, of how few of the exports were being done. this is resolved.